# Xamarin Android: If background set only first fragment visible

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, xamarin

I have a Drawer Layout and 2 Menu Items in the drawer. If I load the app it loads the first fragment correctly. But if I open the drawer and select another menu point it doesn't change the fragment. Really strange is, that if I remove the background color it works, but then it overlaps sometimes.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Call in the drawer:

```
            _list.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string> (this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, itemList);
        _list.ItemClick += (sender, e) => {
            _title = itemList[e.Position];

                var fragmentTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();

                switch(e.Position)
                {
                    case 0:
                    fragmentTransaction.Replace (Resource.Id.content_pane, new MedicineListFragment());
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        fragmentTransaction.Replace (Resource.Id.content_pane, new HistoryListFragment());
                        break;
                };
                fragmentTransaction.Commit ();

                _slidingLayout.SmoothSlideClosed ();
        };
```

First fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/medicine_list_fragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="?android:windowBackground">
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/medicine_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Second fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/history_list_fragment"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="?android:windowBackground">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="foooo2" />
```

Main Layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_pane"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_pane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

Interessting is, if I debug the correct fragment appears, then the screen flickers and the old appears again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had something like this:

```
public void FirstLayoutListener(object sender, EventArgs e){
        if(_slidingLayout.CanSlide () && !_slidingLayout.IsOpen){
            ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);
            ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled (true);
            ActionBar.Title = _title;
        } else {
            ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (false);
            ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled (false);
            ActionBar.Title = _drawerTitle;
        }

        var fragmenTransaction = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction ();
        fragmenTransaction.Add (Resource.Id.content_pane, new MedicineListFragment());
        fragmenTransaction.Commit ();

        _slidingLayout.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout -= FirstLayoutListener;
    }
```

I thought this method is called on the first load only, but it was somehow on every refresh / load of a fragment. Therefore it regreated the first fragment always again.

Regards
NPadrutt